# is normalization of images of objects centred against a white background reasonable before training a network?

Tags: neural-networks, normalization, data-preprocessing

I am trying to train a network to classify grayscale images of two classes say oranges and apples, the apples and oranges are centred against a white background, 
Before training i am doing contrast normalization and whitening to the data, but before that i do mean normalization by stacking all the images and computing the mean of the same pixel position in all the images then substracting it from the pixel intensity value.This is a common practice for natural images, I am wondering if the mean normalization step is not practical for my data (centred objects) ?